# Como pasar props de una función a otra React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy trabajando con un código similar a este en react (faltan más cosas pero me estoy centrando en la parte q me esta dando problemas):

```
const defaultComps = {estilo1, estilo2,...,estilon};

const mainFunction = ({src, renderers, links}) => {
    const comp = {...defaultComps, ...renderers};
    
    const function1 = (p) => {
         const Block = comp.estilo1;
         return(
             <Block>{p.value}</Block>
         )
    }
    
    const customRenderers = {
        render1: function1,
    }
    return <ReactMarkdown source = {src} renderers={customRenderers}>
}
export default mainFunction;
```

Lo que quiero hacer es darle a `function1` su propio archivo e importarla a `mainFunction`, mi problema es q no estoy segura de como pasar a `comp` como un prop para q `function1` pueda interpretarlo de la misma forma en q lo hace estando en `mainFunction`. Alguna idea de como hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Lo que se busca es pasar `function1` como `prop` a `mainFunction`? El patrón común es pasar las props desde padre a hijo, es decir se debería pasar `funcion1` como prop desde el padre de `mainFunction`. Sugiero seguir dicho patrón. Veo que hay dos variables involucradas `p` y `comp`, verifica que  puedes usarlas desde el padre, así declaras `function1` desde el padre y ya solo la pasas como prop.

Comment: No pasarla como un `prop` sino como un `import` de una función normal a un componente en react. Lo q quiero es una manera de q `function1` pueda acceder `renderers` cuando es invocada en `mainFunction`

Comment: Si pudieras elaborar un poco mas el problema y el objetivo, sugiero también modificar el título de la pregunta. Saludos